# Web Scraping Not Working with Certain URLs (No Output Generated)

Tags: web-scraping

I have a Python web scraping code that I'm trying to use on specific URLs, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. When I run the code, there is no output generated on the screen. I've tested the code with different URLs, and it works for most of them, but not for this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

link = 'https://store.wom.cl/equipos/portabilidad'
r = requests.get(link)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

def get_attributes(list_of_elements, list_of_attributes):
    return {a: e.get(a) for a in list_of_attributes for e in list_of_elements}

data = []
pagina_actual = 1

while True:
    for e in soup.select('div.Product-module--container--BMAkS'):  
        precio_element = e.find('s', {'class': 'PhonePrice-module--Pricing__Offer--PFWNc'})
        precio = precio_element.text.strip() if precio_element else 'Precio no encontrado'

        precio_element2 = e.find('h1', {'class': 'PhonePrice-module--Pricing__Price--1hJ1C'})
        precio2 = precio_element2.text.strip() if precio_element2 else 'Precio no encontrado'

        d = {
            'Title': e.find('strong', {'class': 'PhoneTitle-module--Title__Brand--4H8uF'}).text.strip(),
            'Modelo': e.find('strong', {'class': 'PhoneTitle-module--Title__Model--3om16'}).text.strip(),
            'Capacidad': e.select_one('li.PhoneFeatures-module--Features__Item--33b-L:nth-child(1) span.PhoneFeatures-module--Features__Item_KeyValue--3sLyM').text.strip(),
            'RAM': e.select_one('li.PhoneFeatures-module--Features__Item--33b-L:nth-child(3) span.PhoneFeatures-module--Features__Item_KeyValue--3sLyM').text.strip(),
            'Cámara': e.select_one('li.PhoneFeatures-module--Features__Item--33b-L:nth-child(5) span.PhoneFeatures-module--Features__Item_KeyValue--3sLyM').text.strip(),
            'Pantalla': e.select_one('li.PhoneFeatures-module--Features__Item--33b-L:nth-child(7) span.PhoneFeatures-module--Features__Item_KeyValue--3sLyM').text.strip(),
            'Precio anterior': precio,
            'Precio actual': precio2,
            'URL': 'https://store.wom.cl' + e.find('button', {'class': 'PhoneCTA-module--ContainerCTA__CTA--2RCVR false'})['data-url']
        }

        data.append(d)

    print(f'Página {pagina_actual} procesada.')
    pagina_actual += 1

    siguiente_elemento = soup.find('div', {'class': 'item pages-item-next'})
    if siguiente_elemento:
        siguiente = siguiente_elemento.a.get('href')
        r = requests.get(siguiente)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    else:
        break

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('wom.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I went to the website you specified in `link` and the page seemed to not load the items ("Mostrando 0 de 0 equipos"). Maybe that's just me.
2. The website might rely on javascript to load the elements you're trying to get, which means that using requests and Beautifulsoup may not be sufficient to get the elements you want to retrieve. You could look into the Selenium package (or similar) for these cases.

Answer (score 0):

The website that you are using loads data dynamically.  You can scrape this by doing this:

```
import requests

request_link = ("https://store-srv.wom.cl/rest/V1/content/getList?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]="
                "attribute_set_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=11&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1]"
                "[filters][0][field]=type_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=configurable&search"
                "Criteria[pageSize]=18&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=&search"
                "Criteria[filterGroups][10][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filterGroups][10][filters][0]"
                "[value]=1&product_type=3")

response = requests.get(request_link).json()

products = response['items']

for product in products:
    print(product['name'])
```

I found the link I am using in the network tab, in Google's developer tools, and this is an API fetch request link that sends the data on your website  in JSON format.  By requesting its JSON list, you can directly pick out the different attributes you want.  In my example, I got each phone's name, but the JSON list contains so much data there are many more things you can find.